# Dynamically setting height of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div called list which is getting its content from database.
I have set the vertical scroller such that whenever its height exceeds 100px,it will use scroll bar.

Now my problem is when the content of the list gets empty or less than 100px,it is setting to same height of 100px .I want the height of div dynamically as per the content of it and at the same time use vertical scroll bar whenever its height crosses 100px.

```
#list {
height: 100px;
width: 1100px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Any help will be highly apreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max-height:100px` instead of `height:100px`.

You can see the difference here: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5r9YY/)**. Chop the text down to see the div shrink.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - too fast for what?

Comment: I mean you answered the question really fast and I just got here. `:)`

Comment: @j08691 : really too fast mate..gr8

Comment: Sorry all, I'll try to be slower next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
height:auto;
max-height:100px;
```